# How To Display textfield when select item in ComboBox that get the value from Database

Tags: javafx

```
@FXML
void tampilComboMilik(MouseEvent event) {
    String tmp = (String) cmb_milik.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String select_qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_kepemilikan WHERE nama =?";
    try {

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(select_qry);
        pst.setString(1, tmp);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("id_milik");
            txt_warna.setText(add1);

            }

        rs.close();
        pst.close();            
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Text Field in the fxml Class and setVisible to False in the initialize method

like

```
@FXML
private String txt_warna;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        txt_warna.setVisible(false); 
}
```

Now when you hit this method and get the value make it visible like

```
@FXML 
    void tampilComboMilik(MouseEvent event) {
    String tmp = (String) cmb_milik.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); 
    String select_qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_kepemilikan WHERE nama =?"; 
    try {
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(select_qry);
            pst.setString(1, tmp);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                String add1 = rs.getString("id_milik");
                txt_warna.setText(add1);
                txt_warna.setVisible(true);

                }

            rs.close();
            pst.close();            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```